Using tenses with "when"

When I arrived she had been cooking

When she had been cooking(for 2 hours) I arrived


People here taught me that 1 is correct  but 2 requires duration to make sense like "for 2 hours". My question is :does the same apply to the present?

When I arrive she has been cooking

When she has been cooking I arrive


Does 4 require duration to be correct the same as it was with my past version?

Adding a duration to 2. does not make it make any more sense. It implies that you deliberately waited for her to cook for two hours before you arrived, which is an odd statement to make on its own. If you arranged dinner plans around the time that she started cooking, you would never state it in this way.


makes even less sense. That implies that you habitually arrive at her house every time she has been cooking (adding a duration won't help). It sounds more like the tagline for a horror movie.


No-one would ever use sentence (4), and (3) is unnatural unless you are writing a story in the present tense. As many people have said it's not helpful to invent combinations of tenses and ask what they mean. They often don't mean anything useful.

Seconding @roganjosh's comment: This is the problem with using artificial formulas, like cooking and arriving, to ask about tenses. Tenses don't make meaning, contexts do. A totally different context like "When the pasta had been boiling for six minutes I added the spinach" would make perfect sense, but the "cooking/arrived" example feels wrong not for grammar reasons but because the ideas don't work.

It's not about duration. It's about understanding the meaning of the word when. Think of it like this:

When = at a specified point in time

And so your examples look like this:

When I arrived she had been cooking. (At the moment of my arrival she had been cooking)

When she had been cooking I arrived. (This sentence clashes because the tense implies an extended period of time, but when implies a particular moment of time. These are two time markers and they conflict.)

When she had been cooking for 2 hours I arrived. (This is technically correct, because now when points to the end of that 2 hour period, not the whole extended period. But it's not idiomatic. We would reorder the sentence: "She had been cooking for 2 hours when I arrived.")

When I arrive she has been cooking. When she has been cooking I arrive. (No English speaker would say either of these sentences. Again there is a clash of tenses. Arrived implies a particular point in the past, and can fit with when, as discussed above. But the present tense arrive doesn't work the same way. These sentences imply repeated activity. I instantly interpreted "When I arrive..." as "Whenever I arrive...", and the whole image felt weird.)



+1.  When I arrive she has been cooking sounds like something you might hear on the voice-over in a documentary by a French film maker. Or maybe by Werner Herzog.
